# Linking the same User to Multiple Logins on a Rails App with Omnioauth Login for Multiple Sites

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, omniauth, soundcloud, google-oauth

I'm building a rails application where we are asking the user to login via either SoundCloud or Youtube(which is basically just a Google login). The soundcloud login does not give me the users email... and the youtube login does(although I have only setup soundcloud so far).

I'm using the omni-oauth gems for both soundcloud and google, and I have a few questions about how I should set this up. Ideally we want users to login through both youtube, and soundcloud, so that they can pull both of their accounts.

I want to avoid creating a duplication of accounts if a user logs in with both? And I would like to somehow link both accounts? I'm not sure what the best way to do this is? Should I have using Devise as well...?

Comment: Do you **need** users to always login with youtube and soundcloud? Or will you allow them to login using just one of those services? Also, will your service allow logging in with email and password?

Comment: Ashitaka, a user will ideally log in with both, b/c I would like to pull info from both api. That said, they need pick a primary login, and then add a second one.....right now I have 2 user accounts in my database for the same user. One is soundcloud, and one is google...but its the same person. I'm not sure what the best way to link the two is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just posting up my solution, in case anyone else has the same problem in the future. I ended up creating an Authentication model, and set a User has_many authentications, and Authentication belongs_to User. I also ended up creating a devise login, and that acts as the connector between both of my other login's through soundcloud, and google. So, now I have one user account, with info from google, and soundcloud, plus the additional personal user info I need for my site, and thats being handled by devise.